# Is there a way I can pick the value rendered on a Typography in Material ui and assign it to a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a data array that I am mapping onto a material-ui Typography.

```
{
  array.map((item, id)=> <Typography key={id} value={item.name} />)
}
```

The code displays the typography with their respective values on the browser as expected, however, I am trying to set the mapped value of Typography into a state like this...

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

...

```
{
 array.map((item, id) => 
      <Typography key={id} value={item.name} {(e)=>setData(e.target.value)} />
)}
```

This method does not work.
How do I make `data` to be the value of `<Typography/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to store **item.name** within local state? How are you receiving the data that you are mapping through?

Are you trying to store each item you're mapping through and represent key-value pairs of an object within local state? What are you trying to do with the state once you have it?

As far as I know, there's is no way to assign values to local state while you are mapping through an array. However, there are multiple ways to assign the data to local state outside of the return.

Also, what is this line doing?

```
{(e)=>setData(e.target.value)}
```

It seems you're trying to create a controlled input on a Typography component without an onChange prop, as well as on a component that does not take input.

One more aside, although it is not a big deal -

```
{
 array.map((item, id) => 
      <Typography key={id} value={item.name} ..../>
)}
```

**id** here is usually referred to as index

---

**Edited for answer**

I normally use Redux to manage the global state, but the process should be the same for Context Provider:

```
const yourComponent = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState();

  // This is the array you get from the Context Provider
  const yourArray = getArrayFromContextProvider();

  useEffect(() => {
    // If you want to normalize the array data
    if (yourArray) {
      const dataObj = {};
      yourArray.forEach((item, index) => {
        // Make the key unique by using the item id OR you can use index
        dataObj[item.id] = item;
        // OR you can add the item value as the key
        dataObj[item.value] = item;
      });
      setData(dataObj);
    }
    // If you just want to store the array
    if (yourArray) {
       setData(yourArray)
    }
  }, [yourArray]);

  return <div>
    {/* ...Your map */}
  </div>;
};

export default yourComponent
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting the array data pulled from react Context Provider and mapping it to a Typography. I want to set that mapped value to local state. This line `{(e)=>setData(e.target.value)}` was my attempt to save the Typography value to local state.

Is there a better way I can implement this and get the value of one `item.name` ? Assuming this is a card component with dynamically rendered data, how can I post the values of a specific card to backend.

I am not sure whether I am clear enough Im having a hard time explaining my issue. But you seem to understand the problem

Comment: Edited original post with the something that I think should help